# BeautifulSoup Error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I am trying to make a program that will **scrape** a random movie from rotten tomatoes Top 100 Movies Of All Time. Then I want it to print the name of the movie and the Audience Score. I am getting an Attribute Error.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import random

url = "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/"
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"table"})
links = table.findAll("a")
titles = []
hyperLinks = []

for link in links:
  titles.append(link.getText().strip())
  hyperLinks.append(link["href"])

choice = random.randint(0,len(hyperLinks) - 1)
page2 = urlopen(url[:-14] + hyperLinks[choice])
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2,"html.parser")
span = soup.find("span",attrs={"class":"mop-ratings-wrap__percentage"})
print(titles[choice])
print(span.getText().strip())
```

The Error is on the last line where I print span.

https://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/

Comment: Have you checked by doing a `print(span)` to check if it not `None`

Comment: The `soup.find()` function did not find the requested element, so `span` is None.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is `soup2.find()` since that is the previous line and yet you do not use `soup2`

Comment: Rishi Dev your answer was right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `span = soup2.find("span",attrs={"class":"mop-ratings-wrap__percentage"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change soup by soup2

```
span = soup2.find("span",attrs={"class":"mop-ratings-wrap__percentage"})
```